# Outlook 2007 sharing someone else's calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar

In Outlook 2007, is it possible to share another person's calendar?

CEO has his calendar shared, and gave the CFO "Owner" permissions.
The CFO would like to be able to share the calendar with all the department heads.

Is this possible?

**Edit:** We are using Exchange 2003 and Server 2003, running Active Directory.

Comment: What sort of environment are you in (e.g. do you have Exchange and AD)?

Comment: Yes, are you using Exchange, or POP3/IMAP? This is critical to your answer.

Comment: Exchange 2003, with Server 2003, running AD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, since the calendar was already shared, the CFO can just modify permissions, didn't have to re-share or anything...  The "Owner" permission granted him the ability to change permissions of the calendar.

Answer (score 2):

If an Exchange environment, the CFO can add the department heads as Delegates.

In Outlook 2007 this is **Tools > Options** and then **Delegates.** The level of access (read, etc) is managed as the users are added.

Ask the Exchange Administrator to perform this task as it will require changes in permission on the actual mailbox.

Comment: The CEO has made the CFO a delegate with every permission Outlook allows.  However, he wants the CFO to be able to add ADDITIONAL people to CEO's calendar.

Comment: I believe that will require the permissions to be changes on the actual mailbox by the Exchange admin.

Comment: My Exchange Administrator confirms this is possible, but only if he does it.  Thanks